# Can i create my own POD which is using another POD?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I want to create my own framework(POD) which is using another POD library.

My framwork is wrapper on top of existing POD library.

Is it Possible by using Cocoa POD or Is there any alternate solution?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the dependency framework into your podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  [...]

  spec.dependency 'SomeOtherPod'
end
```

When installing your framework with 'pod install' it will automatically fetch the specified pod

More info : https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: Specifically: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency